# Visual Studio 2019 .net standard with linux platform

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

How come visual studio allow me to create a new .net **standard** project on Linux platform?

[image]

Isn't Linux is only in .net core?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean? .net standard and .net core are different things, .net standard isn't related to any platform, .net core is cross-platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be some confusion about the differences between .NET Core and .NET Standard. It's true that only .NET Core runs on Linux (and not the normal .NET Framework), but .NET Standard means a different thing.

It only dictates the base standard library for any .NET implementation, not a specific one. As .NET Core complies with .NET Standard, this is the runtime that'll run your code on Linux, and that's because the option appears there.

In more programmers words, consider .NET Standard an interface, while .NET Core being the concrete implementation for it. The interface knows nothing about the implementation, hence it's platform-agnostic.